# Running .bat file in mintty

Tags: bash, git, batch-file, git-bash, mintty

I am provided a .bat file which some script I need to execute. I have the Git bash mintty console for Windows and want to run it from there. From a normal Windows console it works normally but in mintty I get :

```
$ script.bat
bash: script.bat: command not found
```

How do I do this ?

Comment: You have not shown us how you are attempting to run the batch file.  All you gave us was the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably tried to execute `script.bat` that is located in your current directory. Windows Command Prompt searches the current directory first, finds the script and executes it. Bash never searches an executable file in the current directory, it looks for them files only in the paths declared in `$PATH`.

In order to run a program that is located in a path not specified in `$PATH`, in Bash you have to invoke it using a path that includes a slash (`/`). This means to run the `.bat` script from the current directory you have to invoke it as:

```
$ ./script.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

`cmd /c script.bat`

or

`cmd /c "$( cygpath -w "/full/path/to/script.bat" )"`

Please be noticed that paths in MS and Cygwin have incompatible syntax. So you need convert each other, if you need to run the script using absolute or relative path till the script.

**Update**

After posting my answer I've made some test creating the batch file and running it directly in Cygwin/minty. It works properly with and without `cmd /c`. `$COMSPEC` is set, Cygwin version is 1.7.25 (not fresh but covers a lot of my works).

Comment: Did not produce the expected result.